# How can I output the content of this array from the twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

Ok , so I made a call to the Twitter API to return the statuses of my friends , I did a var_dump and it returned an array of the info .. However , I would only like to catch the PROFILE IMAGEs of my friends .. So this is what I did to catch it and it does not return anything

```
$friends = $connection->get('statuses/friends_timeline'); //method that catches my friends'statuses on Twitter.
var_dump($friends);
```

The loop below is supposed to display the images of my friends .. Below the loop is the sample of what the var_dump returned to me  .. Where am I going wrong ???

```
if( is_array($friends))
{
    shuffle($friends);
}              

for($i=0; $i <=count($friends);$i++)
    if (is_array($friends))
    {
         foreach ($friends[$i] as $key => $value)
         {                                     
             if(array_key_exists("profile_image_url", $friends[$i]))
             {                                   
                 echo "<img src='". $value."' width='100' height='100'/>";
             }

         } 
    }

array(20) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (19) {
    ["id_str"]=>
    string(18) "277310503989149697"
    ["user"]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (37) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(48948037)
      ["default_profile"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["following"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_background_tile"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["id_str"]=>
      string(8) "48948037"
      ["url"]=>
      NULL
      ["profile_sidebar_fill_color"]=>
      string(6) "CCD7DB"
      ["profile_image_url"]=>
      string(66) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1821098433/photo__1__normal.JPG"
      ["utc_offset"]=>
      int(-28800)
      ["contributors_enabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["time_zone"]=>
      string(26) "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Semirindi Makala"
      ["listed_count"]=>
      int(1)
      ["profile_background_color"]=>
      string(3) "fff"
      ["screen_name"]=>
      string(7) "MASE_85"
      ["geo_enabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["protected"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["follow_request_sent"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["location"]=>
      string(13) "Teh internets"
      ["profile_background_image_url"]=>
      string(69) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/422730827/photo__1_.JPG"
      ["friends_count"]=>
      int(15)
      ["verified"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_link_color"]=>
      string(6) "0084B4"
      ["statuses_count"]=>
      int(59)
      ["notifications"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["default_profile_image"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["favourites_count"]=>
      int(0)
      ["lang"]=>
      string(2) "en"
      ["profile_background_image_url_https"]=>
      string(71) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/422730827/photo__1_.JPG"
      ["profile_use_background_image"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["profile_image_url_https"]=>
      string(68) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1821098433/photo__1__normal.JPG"
      ["profile_text_color"]=>
      string(6) "333333"
      ["followers_count"]=>
      int(9)
      ["profile_sidebar_border_color"]=>
      string(6) "A8C7F7"
      ["is_translator"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(30) "Sat Jun 20 06:50:28 +0000 2009"
    }
    ["in_reply_to_user_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_status_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["coordinates"]=>
    NULL
    ["geo"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(30) "Sat Dec 08 07:15:50 +0000 2012"

    ["retweet_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["favorited"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(30) "Sat Dec 08 06:40:59 +0000 2012"
    ["truncated"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["in_reply_to_screen_name"]=>
    NULL
    ["retweeted"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["text"]=>
    string(29) "Sat, 08 Dec 12 06:40:59 +0000"
    ["place"]=>
    NULL
    ["source"]=>
    string(65) "<a href="http://www.europe-zone.com" rel="nofollow">Madscore1</a>"
    ["in_reply_to_status_id_str"]=>
    NULL
    ["id_str"]=>
    string(18) "277301732894179328"
    ["in_reply_to_user_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_status_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["id"]=>
    float(2.7730173289418E+17)
  }
  [7]=>
  object(stdClass)#21 (19) {
    ["in_reply_to_status_id_str"]=>
    NULL
    ["user"]=>
    object(stdClass)#22 (37) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(48948037)
      ["followers_count"]=>
      int(9)
      ["following"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["url"]=>
      NULL
      ["profile_sidebar_border_color"]=>
      string(6) "A8C7F7"
      ["profile_image_url_https"]=>
      string(68) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1821098433/photo__1__normal.JPG"
      ["utc_offset"]=>
      int(-28800)
      ["default_profile"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_background_tile"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Semirindi Makala"
      ["id_str"]=>
      string(8) "48948037"
      ["profile_sidebar_fill_color"]=>
      string(6) "CCD7DB"
      ["screen_name"]=>
      string(7) "MASE_85"
      ["protected"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_image_url"]=>
      string(66) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1821098433/photo__1__normal.JPG"
      ["location"]=>
      string(13) "Teh internets"
      ["contributors_enabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["listed_count"]=>
      int(1)
      ["time_zone"]=>
      string(26) "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
      ["profile_background_color"]=>
      string(3) "fff"
      ["geo_enabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["notifications"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["follow_request_sent"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["lang"]=>
      string(2) "en"
      ["profile_background_image_url"]=>
      string(69) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/422730827/photo__1_.JPG"
      ["friends_count"]=>
      int(15)
      ["statuses_count"]=>
      int(56)
      ["verified"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_link_color"]=>
      string(6) "0084B4"
      ["default_profile_image"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["favourites_count"]=>
      int(0)
      ["profile_background_image_url_https"]=>
      string(71) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/422730827/photo__1_.JPG"
      ["profile_use_background_image"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["is_translator"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["profile_text_color"]=>
      string(6) "333333"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(30) "Sat Jun 20 06:50:28 +0000 2009"
    }
    ["contributors"]=>
    NULL
    ["coordinates"]=>
    NULL
    ["geo"]=>
    NULL
    ["retweet_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["favorited"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(30) "Sat Dec 08 06:28:19 +0000 2012"
    ["in_reply_to_user_id_str"]=>
    NULL
    ["truncated"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["in_reply_to_screen_name"]=>
    NULL
    ["retweeted"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["text"]=>
    string(29) "Sat, 08 Dec 12 06:28:18 +0000"
    ["place"]=>
    NULL
    ["source"]=>
    string(65) "<a href="http://www.europe-zone.com" rel="nofollow">Madscore1</a>"
    ["id_str"]=>
    string(18) "277298543398617088"
    ["in_reply_to_user_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_status_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["id"]=>
    float(2.7729854339862E+17)
  }
  [8]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (19) {
    ["user"]=>
    object(stdClass)#24 (37) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(48948037)
      ["default_profile_image"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["followers_count"]=>
      int(9)
      ["following"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["url"]=>
      NULL
      ["favourites_count"]=>
      int(0)
      ["profile_background_image_url_https"]=>
      string(71) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/422730827/photo__1_.JPG"
      ["profile_sidebar_border_color"]=>
      string(6) "A8C7F7"
      ["utc_offset"]=>
      int(-28800)
      ["profile_background_tile"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Semirindi Makala"
      ["id_str"]=>
      string(8) "48948037"
      ["is_translator"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_sidebar_fill_color"]=>
      string(6) "CCD7DB"
      ["screen_name"]=>
      string(7) "MASE_85"
      ["protected"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_image_url"]=>
      string(66) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1821098433/photo__1__normal.JPG"
      ["location"]=>
      string(13) "Teh internets"
      ["contributors_enabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["default_profile"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["time_zone"]=>
      string(26) "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
      ["profile_image_url_https"]=>
      string(68) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1821098433/photo__1__normal.JPG"
      ["profile_background_color"]=>
      string(3) "fff"
      ["geo_enabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["notifications"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["follow_request_sent"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["listed_count"]=>
      int(1)
      ["lang"]=>
      string(2) "en"
      ["profile_background_image_url"]=>
      string(69) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/422730827/photo__1_.JPG"
      ["verified"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_link_color"]=>
      string(6) "0084B4"
      ["profile_use_background_image"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["friends_count"]=>
      int(15)
      ["description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["statuses_count"]=>
      int(51)
      ["profile_text_color"]=>
      string(6) "333333"
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(30) "Sat Jun 20 06:50:28 +0000 2009"
    }
    ["contributors"]=>
    NULL
    ["coordinates"]=>
    NULL
    ["geo"]=>
    NULL
    ["retweet_count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["favorited"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(30) "Sat Dec 08 06:27:07 +0000 2012"
    ["truncated"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["in_reply_to_screen_name"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_status_id_str"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_user_id_str"]=>
    NULL
    ["retweeted"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["text"]=>
    string(29) "Sat, 08 Dec 12 06:27:07 +0000"
    ["place"]=>
    NULL
    ["source"]=>
    string(65) "<a href="http://www.europe-zone.com" rel="nofollow">Madscore1</a>"
    ["id_str"]=>
    string(18) "277298243392643072"
    ["in_reply_to_user_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_status_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["id"]=>
    float(2.7729824339264E+17)
  }
  [9]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (19) {
    ["user"]=>
    object(stdClass)#26 (37) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(48948037)
      ["followers_count"]=>
      int(9)
      ["profile_image_url_https"]=>
      string(68) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1821098433/photo__1__normal.JPG"
      ["following"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["url"]=>
      NULL
      ["profile_sidebar_border_color"]=>
      string(6) "A8C7F7"
      ["utc_offset"]=>
      int(-28800)
      ["default_profile"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_background_tile"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Semirindi Makala"
      ["id_str"]=>
      string(8) "48948037"
      ["profile_sidebar_fill_color"]=>
      string(6) "CCD7DB"
      ["screen_name"]=>
      string(7) "MASE_85"
      ["protected"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_image_url"]=>
      string(66) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1821098433/photo__1__normal.JPG"
      ["location"]=>
      string(13) "Teh internets"
      ["contributors_enabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["listed_count"]=>
      int(1)
      ["time_zone"]=>
      string(26) "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
      ["is_translator"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_background_color"]=>
      string(3) "fff"
      ["geo_enabled"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["notifications"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["follow_request_sent"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["lang"]=>
      string(2) "en"
      ["profile_background_image_url"]=>
      string(69) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/422730827/photo__1_.JPG"
      ["friends_count"]=>
      int(15)
      ["statuses_count"]=>
      int(50)
      ["verified"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["profile_link_color"]=>
      string(6) "0084B4"
      ["default_profile_image"]=>
      bool(false)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// ***********************************-={ 2012-12-08 - WB }=-***********************************
// COLLECT THE FREINDS ARRAY
// *********************************************************************************************
$friends = $connection->get('statuses/friends_timeline'); //method that catches my friends'statuses on Twitter.





// ***********************************-={ 2012-12-08 - WB }=-***********************************
// PRINTS THE ENTIRE ARRAY TO THE SCREEN
// *********************************************************************************************
// var_dump($friends); //STILL WORKS, BUT TRY THE METHOD BELOW

//This Is Just A Cleaner Way Of Dumping The Array
print "<PRE><FONT COLOR=ORANGE>"; print_r($friends); print "</FONT></PRE>";




// ***********************************-={ 2012-12-08 - WB }=-***********************************
// TO WORK WITH INDVIDUAL KEY / VALUE PAIRS FROM ARRAY
// AS YOU MENTIONED YOU WERE ATTEMPTING TO GET YOUR FRIENDS PIC
// *********************************************************************************************
print "<BR>".$friends[5];  
print "<BR>".$friends[6];
print "<BR>".$friends[7];
print "<BR>".$friends[8];// This One Should Be What You Are Looking For
print "<BR>".$friends[9];
print "<BR>".$friends[10];





// ***********************************-={ 2012-12-08 - WB }=-***********************************
// NOT NEEDED UNLESS YOUR LOOKING TO RANDOMIZE LATER ON
// *********************************************************************************************
//shuffle($friends);//THIS WILL PRINT THE ARRAY IN A RANDOM ORDER EACH TIME IT IS CALLED






// ***********************************-={ 2012-12-08 - WB }=-***********************************
// YOUR IF STATEMENT IS GOOD PRACTICE.
// SO IF WE DO NOT HAVE THE POPULATED ARRAY, LETS STOP HERE
// *********************************************************************************************
if( is_array($friends)){
    $counter = 0; //LETS ADD A COUNTER TO USE IN THE PRINT STATEMENT BELOW
    foreach ($friends as &$friend_data) {//WORK WITH EACH KEY. THERE ARE ALOT OF WAYS TO DO THIS LIKE WITH for(), or explode(), OR array_walk ETC...
        print "Key: ".$counter."<BR>".$friend_data;
        $counter++; //Just Adds 1 To The Counter For Each Loop

    }//CLOSE YOUR FOR EACH STATEMENT
}    //CLOSE YOUR IF ARRAY EXISTS STATEMENT










// ***********************************-={ 2012-12-08 - WB }=-***********************************
// FINALY I CLEARLY SEE IN YOUR CODE AS WELL AS YOUR STATEMENT YOU WANT ONE KEY VALUE PAIR.
// SO HERE IS WHAT YOU ASKED FOR IN YOUR POST.
// *********************************************************************************************
$friends = $connection->get('statuses/friends_timeline'); //COLLECT DATA. POPULATE YOUR ARRAY
//var_dump($friends);   //REMOVE COMMENT IF THE KEY/VALUE PAIR IS WRONG AND SELECT THE RIGHT ONE.
$value = $friends[8];   //stick the right key val pair together and load it into the variable $value
print "<img src='". $value."' width='100' height='100'/>"; //PRINT YOUR BUDDIES PIC TO THE PAGE.
```

It Looks Like #8 But I May Have Miss-Counted.

Allow Me To Explain. The Code Above Will Output 6 keys To Your Browser Window Under The Var Dump. The Array Contains Key Value Pairs So To View The One You Are Wanting Type $arrayname[#];

So id_str Would Be $friends[5].

Printing This Out To Your Browser Will Make It Clear But Like I Said. Hope This Helps.

EDIT.
I Type Like This And It Is Just The Way I Do Things. It Also Falls Under The Freedom Of Speech Act. If Your Not Able To Clearly Read This Than There Is An Option On This Page To Post Your Own Answer. If I Took The Time And Effort To Type Anything Out. I Would Like It To Remain How I Typed It. And I Will Continue Fixing It As Needed.

People That Have Nothing Better To Do But Criticize Other Peoples Way Of Doing Things Need To Get A Life. I Am A Programmer Like Most Other People On This Site Who Takes The Time Out Of My Work Schedule To Help Others With Problems That I Have Ran In To Years Ago Or To This Very Day.

I Have Also Taken The Time To Follow Up On This Guy That Seems To Have A Hard On For Me. And I Soon Found Out That Was Not The Case. He Is Just A Dick To Everyone.

So, If i Type like this. oR iF i tYPE lIKE tHIS. or even like this. I Still Get My Point Across.

Also, Charles, You Are The First Person I Have Ever Seen Say Anything About The Way I Type. Besides My Shift Key Gets The Beating, Not You. In Fact No Charles's Was Harmed In The Creation Of This Message.

There Are Programmers Who Want To Help. Then There The Guys That Have Had A Few Years Under There Belt, Think They Know It All, And Want To Treat All Who They Think Are Less Than Them Like Trash. Please Everyone Follow His Posts And See What Conclusion You Draw.

Comment: I Am Sure Once He Sees This In Action. IE: Copy / Paste What I Have Taken The Time To Type Out, He Would Understand What Is Going On. But For Clarity Sake... I Added A Bit More Detail.

Comment: " ..However , I would only like to catch the PROFILE IMAGEs of my friends .. So this is what I did to catch it and it does not return anything...." By All Means... Explain In Your Words. And With Your Own Typing Habits. Please.

Comment: Sorry, Let Me Explain His Question Better To You. He Would Like To "catch the PROFILE IMAGEs" Of His Friends. So This Is What He Did " to catch it and it does not return anything." One Key Value Pair Referenced. Please Explain Yourself Though. Since You Seem To Be In This Guys Head.